# Not able to use HTML text in setText of collapsing Toolbar in android?

Tags: android, uitextview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, htmltext

I am using collapsing `Toolbar` layout in my android application. while layout is collapse or expand in both case I need collapsing `Toolbar` text displaying my "amount" in green and "balance" in red.
I had try to use HTML like below:

```
collapsingToolbar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='green'>50</font><font color='red'>balance</font>"));
```

I had used `SpannableString` like below:

```
String part1 = " 50";
String part2 = "Balance";
SpannableString str = new SpannableString(part1 + part2);
str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")), part1.length(), str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
collapsingToolbar.setTitle(str);
```

Both did not work in my case. 
Dose someone have some new idea to work in this case.

Comment: please also post what exactly happened in both cases

Comment: The text color is white in both case

Comment: You'll have to do something like Tiago Ornelas suggests, and handle the animation yourself. That title is drawn as a plain string, so any span formatting on it is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a TextView inside the Toolbar widget and set it's text to the HTML formatted one.

Comment: I also need animation move text from center of collapsing layout to top-right as I drag above

Comment: This is not related to your question. Please ask a new one, where you describe your problem, current research, code and expected results

Comment: Don't thing you can achieve that. Either you have the formatted text or that animation

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Spannable word1 = new SpannableString("50");
    word1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.green)), 0, word1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    collapsingToolbar.append(word1);
    Spannable word2 = new SpannableString("Balance");
    word2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color. red)), 0, word2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    builder.append(word2);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(builder);
```

Comment: cannot resolved append in  ' collapsingToolbar.append(word1);'

Comment: @sofquestion9 now check and try it again and let me know.